# Connecting database to MVC application - Error 50 Local database runtime error occurred

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, iis-7

I am having a hard time in connecting my database to my MVC Application. I keep getting the following error, despite the recommendations that I have found online.

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
```

**Background situation:**

I have developed an MVC Web App with User database, and I would like to publish them on another computer. After copying the files to the host computer, however, I was unable to access the SQL Server, with the following error message: Error 50 Local Database runtime error occurred.

**The followings are the steps I have taken from the start of publishing process to the end:**

I have created an MVC Web Application on my personal computer, with a user login authentication as described in Rick Anderson's example: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-sms-and-email-two-factor-authentication. Therefore, with the Web App, I have a default user database created with it.

I then deployed the App to my own C:/inetpub, by using Visual Studio 2013. The publishing method is "File System". I understand that Database publishing is not supported for this publish method. So after the Web App was published, I created a folder named "App_Data" in my C:/inetpub/wwwroot, and copied my mdf and log database from my Project folder in VS2013 into it.

Afterwards, I opened up IIS7 on my computer and set my Default Website's physical property to C:/inetpub/wwwroot. I opened my web browser and I could connect to both the website and my databse (meaning I can login through the website, and it manages to authenticate my login id). So it was all good when the web app was running on my computer.

Next, I had to install the Web App to the host computer where it will be hosted.

So I copied the whole MVC Folder (C:/inetpub/wwwroot) and put it in the host computer's C:/inetpub/wwwroot. Then I did the following settings:

- In the host computer, I gave IIS_IUSRS read/write access to the database.
- I opened MSSQL 2014 SSMS, connected to Server: (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB, and added a new database, i.e. the database.mdf in my C:/inetpub/wwwroot/App_Data. So my user database is registered in SSMS.
- The connection string in my IIS was then changed to (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB because I have MSSQL 2014 installed on the host computer.

  ```
  <add connectionString="Server=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=aspnet-MvcPWy-20140708072924;Integrated Security=true" name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  ```
- ApplicationPool settings for IIS7 was following [this example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gaurav/archive/2013/12/21/deployment-of-sql-express-localdb-on-iis.aspx)

  ```
  <add name="DefaultAppPool">
    <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
  </add>
  ```

Despite all those configurations, however, I am still getting the same error. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could review my steps and see if I have made a mistake or missed some steps in setting this database. Thank you!

Comment: Did you "See the Windows Application event log for error details." like the error message tells you?

Comment: Yes I have. That's why I followed the suggestion from the last bullet, which is to set loadUserProfile="true", because I am getting the same error message as shown in that link.